# Invalid URI with Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, build

I am new to maven, while using mvn install I've got this error, any idea?

thanks in advance

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://maven.mysite.com:9999/repository/npg/data-recovery/${applicationVersion}/data-recovery-${applicationVersion}.pom': escaped absolute path not valid
        at hidden.org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.(HttpMethodBase.java:222)
        at hidden.org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.(GetMethod.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:547)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:372)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:388)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:74)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.resolveTransitiveDependencies(DefaultPluginManager.java:1492)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:435)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:540)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:519)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 04 15:12:56 EET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/35M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<version>${applicationVersion}</version>` somewhere (maybe in this POM or maybe in a parent POM if the version is inherited) but this property is not resolved. You need to define something like this:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <applicationVersion>x.y.z</applicationVersion>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Note that I don't really see the point of using such a property, there is a built in `${project.version}` property that refers to the version of the project (that you can use in dependencies for example). Check the [MavenPropertiesGuide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) for more details on available properties.

Answer (score 1):

The property `${applicationVersion}` is not resolved in the URI path shown:

```
'http://maven.mysite.com:9999/repository/npg/data-recovery/${applicationVersion}/data-recovery-${applicationVersion}.pom'
```

I guess this is a dependency configured in your pom. You should locate "data-recovery" among the dependencies in your pom.xml - my bet is that its `<version>` property is set to `${applicationVersion}`. If so, you should set the concrete version for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue while using a property to set parent pom version in my child module.

You can use maven release plugin to achieve this. Just update version in your parent pom file and run this command to update version in your child module from parent folder:

```
mvn -N versions:update-child-modules
```